# Deploy SharePoint 2010 web application at a different machine

Tags: deployment

I develop SharePoint 2010 web application in Windows 7 + SharePoint 2010 Server machine. I have used Visual Studio 2010 for the development. In my application I have three different projects each for Site Definition, List Definitions and Visual Web parts respectively. Now I need to deploy my application in a different server machine with Windows Server 2008 with VM containing SharePoint Server 2010. Please someone help me with steps in deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VS projects will generate SharePoint packages (WSP) when you package them (right click on the project and package).

On your target environment, you'll need to create a web application then install & deploy the WSP for your site definition (that will be a farm solution). Once done, you'll be able to create a site collection of that template and afterward you'll have to install & deploy the last two WSPs and activate the relevant features to have your list definition & webparts available.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I have deployed the my three wsp files and activated the features. wsp1-contains masterpage, custom css and the custom js files. wsp2-contains list definitions. wsp3-contains webparts. wsp1 and wsp2 were globally deployed and wsp3 was deployed to a web application. Now in the web application I can find all the webparts but not any lists and styles.

Comment: Are you sure the associated feature is activated on the target environment ?

Comment: yes am sure about it. In wsp1 and wsp2 the scope of the feature is web and wsp3 the scope is site.

Comment: Thank you for the supports. I resolved the issue by changing the scope of the globally deployed wsp to "Site" from "Web" and re-deploying the wsps to the web application.

Comment: glad to read it's solved. Good luck for the other tasks :)